# Консоль не показывает текст и программа читатет другой файл

Tags: c#

Не давно начал изучать тему файлы в C# и никак не могу понять:

- Почему консоль не показывает текст?
- Почему он читатет другой файл - `lesson.exe`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В заголовке консоли отображается имя исполняемого файла, который вы запускаете после сборки программы- `lesson.exe`. Внутри же происходит открытие вашего файла `RR.txt`. Чтобы увидеть результаты программы напишите что-нибудь в консоль.

Comment: Текст творения в студию :)

Comment: Написал java как метку. Я не понимаю, он же должен отобразить текст который написан в файле txt, или я что то не то делаю?

Answer (score 1):

Файл `RR.txt` *нет* в папке `C:\`, как вы пишете в вашей программе в комманде:

```
... new FileStream("C:\\RR.txt", .....
```

но в библиотеке `Документы`, т.е. вместо

```
"C:\\RR.txt"
```

нужно писать что-то как "C:\\Users\\*ваше_имя*\\Documents\\RR.txt", где вместо *ваше_имя* будет вероятно *User*:

```
"C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\RR.txt"
```

---

Консоль *не показывает текст*, потому что вы *ничего не вывели* - консоль *ждает* ввод от вас:

```
Console.ReadKey();
```

---

Имя файла с кодом вашей программы наверно есть `lesson.cs`, и так имя вашей программы (после сборки) есть `lesson.exe` - потому оно (вместе с пути) изображается в заголовке консоли.